# Django template url tag with single parameter for url with ORed capture group fails on reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-templates

Not the best title.. anyway:
I have the following URLConf entry:

```
url(r'^events(?:/(?:(?P<event_id>\d+)|(?P<new>new)))?/?$', EventView.as_view(), name='events')
```

Which as you can see, can take no extra path components after events, or a number or the word 'new'. My problem is when trying to do a reverse lookup with one of the two capture groups from within a template. Django doesn't seem to realize that if the template url tag is given a single argument it's ok since my regex says it's either one group or the other.

For instance, say I want to go for:

```
/events/1
```

I'm trying to do so like this:

```
{% url 'social_network:events' event.id %}
```

And I get:

```
Reverse for 'events' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['events(?:/(?:(?P<event_id>\\d+)|(?P<new>new)))?/?$']
```

I also tried with named parameters (event_id=1 instead) to have the parameters be passed in the dictionary but still the same error. Mind you, if I remove one of the ORed capture groups, then it resolves just fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Django can't reverse URLs with optional capture groups, because it can't know what to put there. The best way to deal with this situation is to have multiple entries in the urlconf: one for the no-param version, one with the id, and one with new.

You can still have them all pointing at the same view - although I must say that since the behaviour is obviously different for those three cases, your code would probably be clearer if you had three separate views.

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't be able to do the reverse lookup? if it goes left to right, it should match up to the first group, where it should insert the event.id (assuming lookahead/backtracking or greedy) and then match the $.

Comment: If I go for 3 different URLs though, how do I distinguish them when referring to them?Do I assign different 'name' parameters to them? Like url(regex1, EventView.asView(), name='events.list'), url(regex2, EventView.asView(), name='events.new') etc?

Comment: And actually, it does seem to be able to handle optional groups. If I do this: `url(r'^events(?:/(?P<event_id>\d+))?/?$', EventView.as_view(), name='events')`, it works just fine. And that's a named capturing group inside an optional discard group. Maybe you meant ORed groups? But still, doesn't quite make sense to me.